# How to convert RSA encrypted numbers into text/characters

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I wrote a RSA encryption in Java. I am trying to turn the numbers that it outputs into text or characters. For example if I feed it `Hello` I get:

> 23805663430659911910

However, online RSA encryptions return something to the effect of this:

> GVom5zCerZ+dmOCE7YAp0F+N3L26L

I would just like to know how to convert my numbers into something similar. The number returned by my system is a `BigInteger`. This is what I've tried so far:

```
RSA rsa = new RSA("Hello");
BigInteger cypher_number = rsa.encrypt(); // 23805663430659911910
byte[] cypher_bytes = cypher_number.toByteArray(); // [B@368102c8
String cypher_text = new String(cypher_bytes); // J^��*���

// Now even though cypher_text is J^��*��� I wouldn't care as long as I can turn it back.

byte[] plain_bytes = cypher_text.getBytes(); // [B@6996db8 | Not the same as cypher_bytes but lets keep going.
BigInteger plain_number = new BigInteger(plain_bytes); // 28779359581043512470254837759607478877667261

// plain_number has more than doubled in size compared to cypher_number and won't decrypt properly.
```

Using bytes it the only way I can think of. Can someone please help me understand what I'm supposed to be doing or if it's even possible?

Comment: Base64 decoded output from your unknown online site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally a 2-step process:

1. convert to binary encoding of the number;
2. convert the binary encoding to a text base encoding.

For both steps there are multiple schemes possible.

---

For binary encoding: the PKCS#1 specifications have always included one that converts the number to a *statically sized* integer. To be precise, it describes the number into a statically sized, unsigned, big endian octet string. An octet string is nothing but a byte array.

Now, `BigInteger.toByteArray` returns a dynamically sized, signed, big endian octet string. So you need to implement the possible resizing and removal of initial `00` byte in a separate method, which I have at my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18824707/589259). Fortunately going back to a number is much easier as the Java implementation provides a `BigInteger(int sign, byte[] value)` constructor that reads in an unsigned number and skips leading zero bytes.

Having a standardized and statically sized octet string can be terribly useful, so I would not go for any other scheme.

---

This leaves the conversion to and from text. For that you can (indeed) use the `java.util.Base64` class, which doesn't need much explaining. The only note that I must make is that it converts to an ASCII `byte[]` for some of the methods, so you need to use the `encodeToString(byte[] src)` instead.

Another method would be hexadecimals, but since Java doesn't contain a hex encoder for byte arrays in the base classes, I'd go for base 64 instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. In case you've found this looking for the answer, you just need to encode the numbers into `Base64`.

The following code converts the number into a dynamically sized, signed, big endian encoded integer, and then converts it back into a number using the reverse process.

```
// Encode
BigInteger numbers = new BigInteger("5109763");
byte[] bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(numbers.toByteArray());
String encoded = new String(bytes); // Encoded value

// Decode
byte[] decoded_bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded.getBytes());
BigInteger numbers_again = new BigInteger(decoded_bytes); // Original numbers
```

Comment: That's much better. Note that there is `encodeToString(byte[] src)` which may be more efficient than creating an byte array and then converting to `String`.

Comment: Yes, I am using that now. Thanks for bringing that to my attention it's very helpful.